# Simple Bash and RegEx Questions

Tags: regex, bash, bash4

I'm unable to get a pattern to match properly using regex in bash 4.1. I've read some information on about differences in quotes vs not quotes but I don't think that is my problem.

My goal is to check and make sure that the script is provided a valid ID. A valid ID in this case is a string of 9 digits. It's my understand that a regex expression for that is \d{9}. Given that here is my code snippet to check:

```
id=$1       
if [[ $id =~ \d{9} ]]; then
     echo "This is a vaild ID"
else
     echo "This is not a vaild ID"
fi
```

Then call the script with:

```
 ./script 987654321
```

Something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: You should edit your question to include why you think it isn't working. are  you getting to the else statment? or are you getting a syntax error. Good luck.

Comment: Regexp in Bash (v3 and later) doesn't support `\d`, you can use `[0-9]` or the `[:digit:]` posix character class.

Comment: The fully portable way would be to use a glob pattern, i.e. `case $id in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) echo fine ;; *) die in anguish;; esac`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This will work: if [[ $id =~ [[:digit:]]{9} ]] – David W. 11 hours ago

---

> @David I tried that on bash and it didn't seem to work. – Vivin Paliath 10 hours ago

---

I've just written a test program:

```
#! /bin/bash

for id in 123456789 12345689 1234567890 987654321
do
    if [[ $id =~ ^[[:digit:]]{9}$ ]]
    then
        echo "$id is 9 digits long"
    else
        echo "$id is bad"
    fi
done
```

And I got the following output:

```
DaveBook:~ david$ ./test.sh
123456789 is 9 digits long
12345689 is bad
1234567890 is bad
987654321 is 9 digits long
DaveBook:~ david$
```

I'm using BASH 3.2.48 for Mac OS X and Bash 4.1.10(4) for Cygwin (Wow, the Mac version is **that** old?). I haven't tested this on a Linux box.

What version are you using? Are you doubling the square braces around `:digit:`? It has to be `[[:digit:]]` and not `[:digit:]`.

I also realized I need the `^` and `$` anchors in there because you don't want to match `foo123456789bar` or `1234567890123456790`. Was this an issue you had?

The thing is that `[[:digit:]]` ***should*** have worked. I've used it in many Bash shell scripts thinking it was fairly universal. However, if you have a BASH shell where it doesn't work, I'm going to have to stop using it.

Comment: I don't know what I was smoking earlier, but I just tried it out now and it works. I could have sworn that it didn't work when I tried it the last time because it was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you. Do you have a reference article for finding equvalancies between items such as /d & [[:digit:]] Or are the man pages the best resource?

Comment: Actually, the best source is the Perl documentation. After all, all of the extended regular expression stuff originally came from Perl. Take a look at [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#CHARACTER-CLASSES) and the part about the character classes.

Comment: great thanks ! how would you specify a number up to 9 digits though?

Answer (score 9):

As others already answered you should use `[0-9]{9}` because `\d` is not supported. But another important part is, **you have to use anchors!**

```
^[0-9]{9}$
```

The `^` anchors the regex to the start of the string and the `$` anchors it to the end. If you don't use them your regex will match on every string that contains 9 digits in a sequence, like "abc123456789", "asdf123456789zui" or "123456789FOOBAR".

Comment: Why do you have to put [[ and ]] around :digit:?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if [[ $id =~ [0-9]{9} ]]; then
```

It looks like bash doesn't recognize `\d` as `[0-9]`.

[Bash uses](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) the [Extended Regular Expression dialect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04), which doesn't support `\d`.

According to ERE's grammar (lexical conventions), escaped characters are of the form `\SPEC_CHAR`. `SPEC_CHAR` can be any one of the following:

```
^    .    [    $    (    )    |
*    +    ?    {    \
```

Comment: @David I tested it out and it works now. I have no idea why it didn't work the first time I tried it.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is \d gets turned into d before it's interpreted. Try double escaping.

```
\d{9} => d{9}
\\d{9} => \d{9}
```

Alternatively, you could put it in quotes

```
if [[ $id =~ "\d{9}" ]]
```